# How to transport " for remote execution?

Tags: python, ssh, quotes

I am working on some python tooling to configure remote systems.
One configuration step requires to replace values in a text file.
I thought to do a simple

```
ssh whatever@where.ever sed -i -e s/property=\"true\"/property=\"false\"/g the.remote.file
```

But well, it doesnt work.

I tried shlex + subprocess, I tried pxssh (which I would like to avoid anyway, as it is much slower compared to a ssh call via subprocess). It seems that whatever I try, the quotes around true/false are removed at some level. But the quotes are in that file on the remote system; so sed will do nothing if the quotes are not showing up in the call that is executed on the remote system.

I could get it working when invoking ssh directly from my bash; but from within python ... no chance. In the end, I put that string into a file; use scp to copy that file to the remote system; and then I ran it from there using ssh again.

But still wondering - is there a clean, straight forward way to do this "just using python"?

(Note: I am looking for solutions that work out of box; not something that requires my users to install other "third party" modules like paramiko.)

Update:

This is ... crazy. I just ran this code (which I think looks exactly like the code that is given in the answer --- I added the .format() afterwards to easily hide username/ip from the posted text):

```
cmd_str= 'ssh {} "cat ~/prop"'.format(target)
subprocess.call(cmd_str, shell=True)

cmd_str= 'ssh {} "sed -i -e s/property=\"true\"/property=\"false\"/g ~/prop"'.format(target)
subprocess.call(cmd_str, shell=True)

cmd_str= 'ssh {} "cat ~/prop"'.format(target)
subprocess.call(cmd_str, shell=True)`
```

and I get:

```
property="true"
property="true"
```

Could that depend on the configuration of the sshd on the remote system?

Comment: Have you tried `sed -i -e 's/property="true"/property="false"/g' the.remote.file`? BTW, most versions of `sed` allow you to supply an extension argument to the `-i` option, which tells `sed` to back up the original file, eg. `sed -i~ 's/this/that/g' filename` will modify `filename` and save the original to `filename~`

Comment: I tried all kind of things; and actually I started with ' around the sed expression.But it seems that these external single, double, whatever quotes ... are all eaten up; either by shlex; or by subprocess. And keeping a backup isn't necessary; as well ... I know what I am doing ;-)
(and we are basically talking about test systems that are one-time configured before our automated testing starts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything worked fine for me, I tried this:

```
In [1]: import subprocess
In [2]: cmd = 'ssh ubuntu@192.168.56.101 "sed -i -e s/property=\"true\"/property=\"false\"/g ~/cfg.cfg"'
In [3]: subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
Out[3]: 0
```

and as shell=True can be unsafe I also tried this:

```
In [4]: parts = ['ssh', 'ubuntu@192.168.56.101', '`sed -i -e s/property=\"true\"/property=\"false\"/g ~/cfg.cfg`']
In [5]: subprocess.call(parts)
Out[5]: 0
```

In both cases my file was changed.

**UPDATE:** shlex output

```
In [27]: shlex.split(cmd)
Out[27]: 
['ssh',
 'ubuntu@192.168.56.101',
 'sed -i -e s/property=true/property=false/g ~/cfg.cfg']
```

Also note, In the first case I use double quotes for the remote command but in the second case I use back quotes for the command.

**UPDATE 2:**

```
In [9]: subprocess.call(['ssh', 'ubuntu@192.168.56.101', 'cat ~/cfg.cfg'])
property="true"
Out[9]: 0
In [10]: subprocess.call(['ssh', 'ubuntu@192.168.56.101', '`sed -i -e s/property=\\"true\\"/property=\\"false\\"/g ~/cfg.cfg`'])
Out[10]: 0
In [11]: subprocess.call(['ssh', 'ubuntu@192.168.56.101', 'cat ~/cfg.cfg'])
property="false"
Out[11]: 0
```

**UPDATE 3:**

```
In [22]: cmd = 'ssh ubuntu@192.168.56.101 \'`sed -i -e s/property=\\"true\\"/property=\\"false\\"/g ~/cfg.cfg`\''
In [23]: subprocess.call(['ssh', 'ubuntu@192.168.56.101', 'cat ~/cfg.cfg'])
property="true"
Out[23]: 0
In [24]: subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
Out[24]: 0
In [25]: subprocess.call(['ssh', 'ubuntu@192.168.56.101', 'cat ~/cfg.cfg'])
property="false"
Out[25]: 0
In [26]: shlex.split(cmd)
Out[26]: 
['ssh',
 'ubuntu@192.168.56.101',
 '`sed -i -e s/property=\\"true\\"/property=\\"false\\"/g ~/cfg.cfg`']
```

Comment: Interesting; guess I have to revisit my code tomorrow. Just for the sake of it: does it also work when you use shlex.split(cmd) as input to subprocess?
Besides - which version of python are you working with?

Comment: I tested this on Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.0

Comment: Please see my update to the question - it simply doesn't work for me?!

Comment: Ah.. I see.. my code worked because I didn't use double quotes, so I had `property=true` instead of `property="true"`, sorry. I has made more tests and my first variant stopped to work, but still a variant with back quotes work with some backslashes added, see my update 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for resolving this. I still consider to keep my initial solution (scp a bash script and execute that via ssh); as it seems much simpler compared to this very complicated expression. But at least it is possible; and hopefully helpful to others.